# Unable to Create Two Distinct Instances of a Class

Tags: python

I'm encountering a strange issue. I have a file, history.py with the following code:

```
from speech_controls.nav_object import NavObject

    """Sets up the chat and text history buffers."""

    chat_history = NavObject()
    text_history = NavObject()
```

In other modules, I import history, and do something such as:

```
history.chat_history.AddItem(some_str)
```

For some reason Python appears to be creating one object rather than two, as the above code should imply. That is, text_history and chat_history point to the same object. Does anyone have any idea why this might be occurring? Also, if there is a more Pythonic way to do this I'd definitely like to know.

Comment: Are you sure `NavObject` is not a singleton class?

Comment: I don't implement any functionality to insure only one instance of NavObject can exist, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @MikeF: Please post the code of `NavObject` class here. It is obviously an issue with the way it works. Also your code is incorrect (see the indentation that is displayed within your question and correct).

Answer (score 3):

Stop using class attributes. Initialize your attributes in the initializer.

### Wrong:

```
class Foo(object):
  bar = []
  baz = {}
```

### Right:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.bar = []
    self.baz = {}
```

Comment: I don't believe I'm doing that in any of my classes. NavObject's attributes are initialized in the constructor. I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: @MikeF: You need to post your __init__ method (or at least some minimal version of it), otherwise folks won't be able to figure it out. The answer above is the problem about 99% of the time in these cases.